# how to add fields on button click without duplicating values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to create a form to add a product , the product has many suppliers and there are many attributes for each supplier's product so what i want to do is such as this photo
[image]

when i click on add icon it will duplicate the fields that in black square
the fields in blue square are working good duplicating and adding as expected
but the fields in green square when i press on add icon it will duplicate the fields and the values of the fields so when i choose a type in the first black square it will have the same value in the two fields , is there any solution or better way to do it ?
this is my code

```
FutureBuilder<List<Supplier>>(
                      future: fetchSuppliers(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 
                          final List<Supplier>? suppliers = snapshot.data;
                          final List<String>? Suppliernames =
                          suppliers?.map((Supplier) => Supplier.supplierName).toList();

                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: supplierslist.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Column(
                                children: [

                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              final removedValue = supplierslist[index].SupplierName;
                                              if (removedValue.isNotEmpty) {
                                                selectedValues.remove(removedValue); // Remove the value from selectedValues
                                              }
                                              if (supplierslist.length > 1) {
                                                supplierslist.removeAt(index);
                                                NoStockAvailable.removeAt(index);

                                                //Dheight = Dheight-50;
                                              }
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        DropdownButton(
                                          value: supplierslist[index].SupplierName.isNotEmpty ? supplierslist[index].SupplierName : null,
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                          items: Suppliernames?.map((Name) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                              value: Name,
                                              child: Text(Name),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                             
                                             
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              if (supplierslist.length < suppliers!.length) {
                                                supplierslist.add(SupplierChose(SupplierName: '', SupplierID: 0));
                                                NoStockAvailable.add(false);
                                                //Dheight = Dheight+50;
                                              }
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              FutureBuilder<List<AttributeNames>>(
                                        future: fetchAttributes(),
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    
                                            final List<AttributeNames>? Attributes = snapshot.data;
                                            final List<String>? names =
                                            Attributes?.map((AttributeNames) => AttributeNames.AttributeName).toList();
                                            return ListView.builder(
                                              itemCount: Attributelist.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return Column(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        IconButton(
                                                          icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              final removedValue = Attributelist[index].AttName;

                                                              if (removedValue.isNotEmpty) {
                                                                selectedAtt.remove(removedValue); // Remove the value from selectedValues
                                                              }
                                                              if (Attributelist.length > 1) {
                                                                Attributelist.removeAt(index);
                                                                SelectedID.removeAt(index);
                                                                NoStockAvailable.removeAt(index);
                                                              }
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                       
                                                        DropdownButton(
                                                          value: Attributelist[index].AttName.isNotEmpty ? Attributelist[index].AttName : null,
                                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                                          items: names?.map((Name) {
                                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                              value: Name,
                                                              child: Text(Name),
                                                            );
                                                          }).toList(),
                                                       
                                                      FutureBuilder<List<AttributeValues>>(
                                                            future: fetchAttributesVal(),
                                                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                                           
                                                                final List<AttributeValues>? AttributesVal = snapshot.data;
                                                                final names = AttributesVal
                                                                    ?.where((AttributeValue) => AttributeValue.AttributeID == SelectedID[index]) // Filter based on AttributeID
                                                                    .map((AttributeValues) => AttributeValues.AttributeValue)
                                                                    .toList();
                                                
                                                                return Column(
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Row(
                                                                      children: [
                                                                        DropdownButton(
                                                                          value: names!.contains(AttributeVallist[index].AttVal) ? AttributeVallist[index].AttVal : null,
                                                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                                                          items: names.map((Name) {
                                                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                                              value: Name,
                                                                              child: Text(Name),
                                                                            );
                                                                          }).toList(),
                                                                         
                                                                        Container(
                                                                          width: 150,
                                                                          child: CustomTextField(
                                                                            Controller: Attributelist[index].AttstockController,
                                                                            text: 'المخزون',
                                                                            //Controller: supplierslist[index].stockController,
                                                                          ),
                                                                          
                                                        IconButton(
                                                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              if (Attributelist.length < Attributes!.length) {
                                                                Attributelist.add(AttributeChose(AttName: '', AttID: 0));
                                                                AttributeVallist.add(AttributeValChose(AttVal: '', AttID: 0));
                                                                SelectedID.add(1);
                                                                NoStockAvailable.add(false);
                                                              }
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                        ),
```